# Variable visibility in object-oriented PHP

Tags: php, oop

If a property is defined in a child class, is that property available inside the parent class's methods? I understand that the parent's properties are inherited by the child, but are the child's properties available in the parent? For example:

```
class My_Parent {
    public function echoVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class My_Child extends My_Parent {
    public $var = 'Henry';
}

$obj = new My_Child;
$obj->echoVar(); // Henry or 'undefined'?
```

Comment: @Rizier123: Incorrect, but not for the reason you describe.

Comment: You should enhance your question replacing the `// Henry or 'undefined'?` comment with the actual output. As it's know, you suggest you didn't even try your own code, which is probably not the case.

Comment: You are asking for the output of your code?  Why not just run it and you will see?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I think we don't talk about the same thing. I mean in general the "parent" class can't know from which class it gets extend so it doesn't know anything about the class/it doesn't know when and where it gets extended

Comment: @Rizier123: Correct. The OP's question is misleading, he's really asking about scopes, but in practice, his question sounds like he is asking if there is two-way inheritance in PHP.

Comment: FYI: You use Parent in your code which is a reserved word and `var` is maybe also not the best choice, since there is also a keyword with the same name

Comment: @Rizier123 got rid of the reserved word to try to make things a little clearer. Seems to be some confusion over what I'm asking here so I also reworded my question slightly.

Comment: http://codepad.org/6wAp5OWa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class extension is pretty simple: your object will contain all the methods, as you expect. Also, any public variable will be there, **in order of precedence** (a child variable can overwrite a parent one).

In your case, your `Parent` is defining a method which will **attempt** to find a variable called `$var` , which does exist in the child class! Everything goes as normal and Henry is returned. Sandbox here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2eb0b764c2be94755ce300deeaa2ad0714d82bcf

However, please run your code next time. Okay? All this could have been done without having to ask the question and would have saved everyone time.

Comment: The question is not about getting the result of the run, but about understanding how inheritance works. Even if it would print 'Henry', it is still interesting how this happens. And you gave an answer!

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko: Tried to cover all bases on a misleading question. :p

Comment: It's problematic if the $var property ___doesn't exist___ in the child class; in practical terms, design your apps cleanly so that the parent can know for certain that a $var property exists by defining the property in the parent

Comment: @MarkBaker: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Also watch out for gotchas if $var is defined in both parent and child with different values

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker for your comment on good practice (i.e. make sure to define the property in the parent). I'll do that.